# GoogleApiClient not connected on service started on boot

Tags: android, android-service, google-api-client

I am using GoogleApiClient for listening for location on a Service that starts on boot, through a BroadcastReceiver that listens to android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED .

```
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent serviceA = new Intent(context, ServiceA.class);
        startWakefulService(context, serviceA);
    }
```

On the service I use:

```
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(ServiceB.this)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(mConnectionCallbacks)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(mOnConnectionFailedListener)
        .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
```

The service starts on boot, but my problem is that neither mConnectionCallbacks nor mOnConnectionFailedListener are ever called.

Is there something wrong with what I'm doing. This way to call GoogleApiClient works well when I use it on Activities or on Services started by Activities.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;

import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

public class YourActivity extends Activity implements  GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener    {

protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
.addConnectionCallbacks(this)
.addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
.addApi(LocationServices.API)
.build();
}


@Override
protected void onStart() {
super.onStart();


ConnectivityManager cm =
(ConnectivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null &&
activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();


if (isConnected) {


mGoogleApiClient.connect();

}

}


/**
* Runs when a GoogleApiClient object successfully connects.
*/
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
//do your works here. it is connected now
}


 @Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
    // The connection to Google Play services was lost for some reason. We call connect() to
    // attempt to re-establish the connection.


    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}


@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    // Refer to the javadoc for ConnectionResult to see what error codes might be returned in
    // onConnectionFailed.


}
```

Comment: Are methods related to location also dependent on NetworkInfo? Would this work when offline?

Comment: @buzoherbert this method is recommended officially by android here https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/BasicLocationSample And it is based on Google playservice. I used network info just for checking whether internet connection is alive or not. you can ignore it... thanks

Comment: Thank you, but then this doesn't address my question. I have the same implementation, but on a service that starts on boot. And that's where it doesn't work.

Comment: tried by implementing LocationListener ? cuz it is working for me